# how to close the option of flowing display in one map in SuperMap

Tags: supermap-gis

how to close all the options in one map that means to close text flow display.Closing the option of one layer by the other one is so tired if there are hundreds of layers.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE!  To try and make your question clearer would you be able to describe your steps and where you are stuck in more detail, please?  It may also be useful to include a screenshot or two.